# Conversation yammer feed webpart update dynamically topic id (SharePoint online Modern page)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, migration, modern-pages, yammer

I'm working on a SharePoint online environment and migrated classic sharepoint page to modern site using pnp powershell script. I have around 2000 site pages.

I have yammer feed in classic page which is not migrated during migration.

**Is there any way to migrate yammer feed from classic page to modern page as conversation feed webpart and set Topic id, search source dynamically using pnp powershell**

I am trying below pnp powershell script :

$jsonObj = '{​​​​​​"type":"Topic","showPublisher":true,"id":"Yammer_x0020_Topic_x0020_ID"}​​​​​​'

Add-PnPClientSideWebPart -Page "Test.aspx" -DefaultWebPartType YammerFullFeed -WebPartProperties $jsonObj -Section 1 -Column 1 -Order 1

[image: Please click here to see Conversation webpart layout]

Comment: Please follow this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-conversations-yammer-webpart-in-sharepoint-modern-page-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this link and solve my problem

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-conversations-yammer-webpart-in-sharepoint-modern-page-using-powershell/